# Verify proof : Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. Prove that there exists a set $C$ such that $x∈C ⇔ x∈A ⊕ x∈B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

> Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. Prove that there exists a set $C$ such that $x∈C ⇔ x∈A ⊕ x∈B$

So, I begin considering the sufficient condition. Then, I use **Axiom Schema of Comprehension** : $∀λ,∃δ,∀x[ x∈δ ⇔ x∈λ ∧ P(x) ]$, like this :
$∃C,∀x[ x∈C ⇔ T ∧ x∈A ⊕ x∈B ]$
So, the doubt I have, regards that $T$. Can I consider that $x∈WhateverSet$ (sorry for being so informal), and just set $x∈λ$ to **$T$rue**, so I can

$x∈C ⇔ T ∧ x∈A ⊕ x∈B$

$x∈C ⇔ x∈A ⊕ x∈B$.

?

If not, then what should I do instead, to prove this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set $\lambda = A \cup B$

Comment: Assuming $\oplus$ means "or", you need the axiom of union as well as comprehension. Otherwise you don't know what set $C$ should be comprehended from.

Comment: It's an exclusive or.

Comment: Ok. You still need union.

Comment: Define your unusal notation ⊕.

Comment: @WilliamElliot We just clarified that it means "exclusive or".